# Whats the name of that short story series online about a post apocalyptic world?

Tags: story-identification, post-apocalyptic

All I can remember is I originally watched it on syfy's website ....after it was gone I had to watch the others on YouTube ..I never finished watching them but would LOVE TO..
The man wakes up not knowing what has happened and I believe he used to be a cop if I remember correctey. There is bits I can remember about the 4 horsemen of the apocalypse

Comment: Welcome to Scifi.stckexchane. Please add information like when did you watch it, language, country of origin. That might help people to figure out.

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE, user56380.  You logged in a couple of weeks after I posted my answer below --- is it correct?  If so, feel free to click the checkmark the left of the answer.   This tells us that your query has been resolved.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

This is ***Amnesia***, whose plot is described on [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3187362/?ref_=tt_ov_inf) as:

> *Man wakes up in a post-apocalyptic world with amnesia and is looking for his family despite being pursued by a ruthless army.*

There doesn't appear to be a formal relationship between the project and the Scyfy Channel.  The series' creator, John Wayne Bosley, had made a pilot and was hoping for Scyfy to pick it up as a mini-series.  Scyfy appears to have posted the pilot (or parts of it) on its web site, perhaps to gauge audience demand.

It doesn't seem to have gotten a pick-up as of this time, which is probably why you had to see the rest of the episodes on YouTube.

[Six episodes](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3187362/episodes?ref_=tt_ep_epl) have been made so far.

There is also a [Kickstarter fund](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/jbmovies/amnesia-tv-show-series/description) that's been organized to keep the show going, so if you like it enough, you may wish to contribute to it.

Comment: youtube doesn't have it, as you say. sadly.